# R - looping through column differentials

Tags: r

let's assume we have 4 vectors

```
a <- c(200,204,209,215)
b <- c(215,220,235,245)
c <- c(230,236,242,250)
d <- c(240,242,243,267)
```

I basically want to create a loop which creates the differentials between each pair, and then calculate the Z scores for those differentials. So something like scale(d-a). How do I create the loop that basically goes scale(b-a), then scale(c-a), scale(d-a) etc? many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can place it in a `list` and use `combn` to get the combinations and then apply the difference

```
lst1 <- list(a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d)
out <- combn(lst1, 2, FUN = function(x) scale(Reduce(`-`, x))[,1])
colnames(out) <- combn(names(lst1), 2, FUN = paste, collapse='_')
out
#            a_b        a_c        a_d        b_c       b_d        c_d
#[1,]  0.9108601  1.2009612  0.1290994 -0.7643506 -0.753390 -0.2219686
#[2,]  0.7759179  0.2401922  0.3872983 -0.9441978 -0.360317  0.3699477
#[3,] -0.5735045 -0.2401922  0.9036961  0.6744270  1.474024  1.1098432
#[4,] -1.1132735 -1.2009612 -1.4200939  1.0341214 -0.360317 -1.2578222
```

As @AlexR mentioned in the comments, if the attributes are important, then remove `[,1]` and keep it as a `matrix` of 1 column

```
out <- combn(lst1, 2, FUN = function(x) scale(Reduce(`-`, x)), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: NB this approach loses the scaling attributes (`scaled:center` and `scaled:scale`) needed for reconstruction of the original values.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Single named variables don't lend themselves too well to "looping".
Let's use a `list()` of vectors instead:

```
vecs <- list(
    a = c(200,204,209,215),
    b = c(215,220,235,245),
    c = c(230,236,242,250),
    d = c(240,242,243,267)
)
```

This allows us to apply a function to all pairs using `combn`

```
scale_diff <- function(subset) {
    z <- scale(subset[[1]] - subset[[2]])
    colnames(z) <- paste(names(subset), collapse = " - ")
    z
}

z_scores <- combn(vecs, 2, scale_diff, simplify = FALSE)
```

Now `z_scores` is a list of 6 matrices (column vectors). The column names show you which vectors were subtracted before scaling.